# How to add child records to parent record variable in apex

Tags: apex, soql

I'm getting a parent record which is Account **acc**, and a list of Contacts **listContact** from another process.

Now in order to proceed further I need to do something I could do like:

```
Account acc = [select Id, (select Id from Contacts) from Account limit 1];
```

I tried to do `acc.Contacts = listContact;` which is a compile time error. (Field is not writeable: Account.Contacts)
I am able to do `acc.Contacts.addAll(listContact);` but when I access/print acc.Contacts, it returns nothing.

Is there any way to assign the related child record to the parent variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported as of now, whereas you can set the parent object using `putSObject(fieldName, value)`. But there is no function like `putSobjects()` to set the child records, again you can get the child objects using `getSObjects(fieldName)`.

To overcome your problem, either you can create a `Map<Id, Contact[]>`, or a wrapper class. Using a map is useful for most of the cases, while the wrapper is needed if you are iterating this data on UI.

[Refer SObject Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#:~:text=getSObject(fieldName),access%20values%20for%20external%20IDs.)

Comment: Yeah I knew about the map solution, and now I need to make changes in the whole method. as my method is being called from another place as well, where I am querying, but my current implementation sends data itself. I tried to play with JSON serialize and deserialize as well, which I didn't find nice. Thanks for the answer..!